# Are time-dependent Banach space-valued functions a Frechét space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces, frechet-space

Consider a family of Banach spaces $(\mathcal{B}_{t},\Vert\cdot\Vert_{t})_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ and define the space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\bullet})$ where smootheness has to be understood in the sense of the Frechét (total) derivative. Now, let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a compact interval. We set

$$\Vert f\Vert_{I}:=\int_{I}\Vert f(t)\Vert_{t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

for all $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\bullet})$.

> Is the space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\bullet})$ a Frechét space with respect to topology induced by the family of seminorms $(\Vert \cdot\Vert_{I})_{I\subset\mathbb{R}}$?

**My idea:** First of all, the family of seminorms can be reduced to a countable one by taking a compact exhaustion of $\mathbb{R}$. Secondly, we can estimate
$$\min_{t\in I}\Vert f(t)\Vert_{t}\leq \Vert f\Vert_{I}\leq\max_{t\in I}\Vert f(t)\Vert_{t},$$
which maybe can be used to argue that $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}_{\bullet})$ is complete.

Comment: It's not clear to me what it means for a map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \bigcup_t B_t$ such that $f(t) \in B_t$ to be Frechet differentiable. In what sense is that union a topological vector space? But anyway I'd expect the answer to the question to be no since if I consider the case where each $B_t = \mathbb{R}$ then unless there is something strange in the details I don't follow, in that setting your question should essentially be asking if the smooth functions are complete as a subset of $L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1(\mathbb{R})$